# Sampling triangle mesh obtained with Delaunay function

Tags: 3d, sampling, delaunay

I have a colection of 3d cloud points such as the one that follows, representing a 3d shape:

[image]

My goal is to increase the number of points on each cloud so that I obtain more 'continuous' clouds. Also it would be important to be able to set the number of points to sample so that every cloud has the same number of points.

I was thinking of using the function delaunay in order to obtain a triangle mesh such as the one that follows

[image]

So that afterwards I could sample it and obtain a smoother cloud. Is there any straightforward way to sample the delaunay mesh?

Or else, do you think there is a better way to achieve this goal without creating a triangle mesh?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the dual of the delaunay triangulation,ie. the voronoi diagram and apply Loyd's algorithm and move the vertices to the center of gravity of the voronoi cell.